# Misaligned content in table cells

Tags: html, css, text, html-table

I am making some table content and got some problems.
When i want to add more text to first table column, it adds extra space do all other columns.
Here u can see what i am saying about
[image]

U can check my fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbj6ccj5/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<table id="mytable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="" />
                <span>some text<br>asdasd<br>asdas</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="" />
                <span>some text</span>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
    #mytable{
    width:400px;
}
#mytable tr td{
    padding:10px;
}
#mytable tr td img{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the `vertical-align` for your `td` elements

```
#mytable tr td{
    padding:10px;
    vertical-align: top; /* Add this */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbj6ccj5/3/)

Comment: @Crion also, if you are using an `img` make sure you use `display: block;` for those images else it will leave white space below your image..

Comment: @Mr.Alien `vertical-align` is a better approach instead of  `display: block;` to remove the white space for images and I was 5 sec. late... +0001 lol :)

Comment: @MaryMelody sometimes it's more consistent to add display block to images from email tables when vertical-align top doesn't seem to work in some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by using `vertical-align: top;` to `#mytable tr td`

### JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbj6ccj5/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<table id="mytable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="" /> <span>some text<br>asdasd<br>asdas</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="" /> <span>some text</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
#mytable{
    width:400px;
}
#mytable tr td{
    padding:10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#mytable tr td img{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add padding for

```
#mytable tr td{
padding:10px;
vertical-align: top; /* Add this */
}
```

Your issue will resolve.